# How to interpret and transform the values predicted by Keras classifier?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm training my Keras model to predict whether, with the provided data parameter, it will make a shot or not and it will represent in such a way that 0 means no and 1 means yes. However, when I try to predict it I got values that are float.

I've tried using the data that is exactly the same as train data to get 1 but it does not work.

I used the data below to tried the one-hot encoding.

https://github.com/eijaz1/Deep-Learning-in-Keras-Tutorial/blob/master/keras_tutorial.ipynb

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
#read in training data
train_df_2 = pd.read_csv('diabetes_data.csv')

#view data structure
train_df_2.head()

#create a dataframe with all training data except the target column
train_X_2 = train_df_2.drop(columns=['diabetes'])

#check that the target variable has been removed
train_X_2.head()

#one-hot encode target column
train_y_2 = to_categorical(train_df_2.diabetes)

#vcheck that target column has been converted
train_y_2[0:5]

#create model
model_2 = Sequential()

#get number of columns in training data
n_cols_2 = train_X_2.shape[1]

#add layers to model
model_2.add(Dense(250, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols_2,)))
model_2.add(Dense(250, activation='relu'))
model_2.add(Dense(250, activation='relu'))
model_2.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

#compile model using accuracy to measure model performance
model_2.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(patience=3)
model_2.fit(train_X_2, train_y_2, epochs=30, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor])


train_dft = pd.read_csv('diabetes_data - Copy.csv')
train_dft.head()

test_y_predictions = model_2.predict(train_dft)
print(test_y_predictions)
```

I wanted to get

```
[[0,1]
[1,0]]
```

However, I am getting

```
[[0.8544417  0.14555828]
 [0.9312985  0.06870154]]
```

Additionally, can anyone explain to me what does this value 0.8544417 mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, you may interpret the output of a model with a softmax classifier at the top as the confidence scores or probabilities of classes (because the softmax function normalizes the values such that they would be positive and have a sum of 1). So, when you provide the model with a true label of `[1, 0]` this means that this sample belongs to class 1 with probability of 1, and it belongs to class 2 with probability of zero. Therefore, during training the optimization process tries to get as close as possible to that label, but it would never **exactly** reach [1,0] (actually due to softmax it might get as close as [0.999999, 0.000001], but never [1, 0]).

But that is not a problem, because we are interested to get just close enough and know the class with the highest probability and consider that as the prediction of the model. And you can easily do that by finding the index of the class with maximum probability:

```
import numpy as np

preds = model.predict(some_data)
class_preds = np.argmax(preds, axis=-1) # e.g. for [max,min] it gives 0, for [min,max] it gives 1
```

Further, if you are interested to convert predictions to either [0,1] or [1,0] for any reason, you can just round the values:

```
import numpy as np

preds = model.predict(some_data)
round_preds = np.around(preds)   # this would convert [0.87, 0.13] to [1., 0.]
```

**Note:** rounding only works properly with two classes, and not when you have more than two classes (e.g. [0.3, 0.4, 0.3] would become [0, 0, 0] after rounding).

**Note 2:** Since you are creating the model using Sequential API of Keras, then as an alternative to `argmax` approach described above you can directly use `model.predict_classes(some_data)` which gives you the exact same output.