# How to determine the predicted class in Keras classifier model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, classification, conv-neural-network

I trained a model based on [this tutorial](https://medium.com/data-science-101/transfer-learning-57ce3b98650). Now, when I use `model.predict` for a single image the output values are `[[0.19530062 0.80469936]]`.

How can I interpret this response? By that I mean what do the two values represent, i.e. to which class does each value belong to? If I'm choosing for cats vs dogs, then how can I determine based on the above output values that the prediction is a cat or a dog?

Comment: Do the question (after my edit) and the answer correspond to what you meant?

Comment: @desertnaut Actually, I closed it as a dup first (see [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61490452/revisions)) but the OP objected that decision and edited the question to clarify that finding the class mapping is of interest (which has not been covered in the answer I linked to). So I reopened and added the answer for that specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know what those values mean, then you can find the answer here: [How to interpret and transform the values predicted by Keras classifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57204355/2099607)

However, if you want to find out which class has been mapped to zero and one in `ImageDataGenerator` after using `flow_from_directory` method, then you can use the `class_indices` attribute:

```
class_mapping = train_data_gen.class_indices
```

From [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory):

> **classes:** Optional list of class subdirectories (e.g. `['dogs', 'cats']`). Default: `None`. If not provided, the list of classes will be automatically inferred from the subdirectory names/structure under `directory`, where each subdirectory will be treated as a different class (and the order of the classes, which will map to the label indices, will be alphanumeric). **The dictionary containing the mapping from class names to class indices can be obtained via the attribute `class_indices`.**